# Mongo aggregattion with sum

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a question. How can I make a sum at specific row in mongo aggregation module.

My document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "315"
    "city" : "Dallas",      
    "population" : 3400,
    "state" : "Unknown"
}
```

How can I made an aggregation based on state and count/sum population?
Y tried this, but something is wrong:

```
db.mydb.aggregate([{"$group":{"$state":"$state", "population":$sum}}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify "_id" at aggregation group and "population" doesn't refer to your "population" item at document, it refers to the result item. So you must do something like that:

```
db.mydb.aggregate([
    {"$group":{"_id":"$state", "populationresult":{$sum:"$population"}}}
])
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Change from "should" to **must**. It is **required**. And fix your spelling please. Also as a general documentation term, please use `db.collection` as a form unless you are explicitly using the same "collection" name as used in the question. Please do not use "whatever" you used in your testing, as it confuses the issue.